# DNN - Rendered aspx page show data similar to binary data

Tags: dotnetnuke, upgrade

I have a DNN site and I updated it to a newer version 5.6.4.

After I've logged in, it redirects me to my page. Instead of the page, it shows me some unrecognizable character paragraph, not the actual UI. Below is what is shown to me.

Site URL: `http://localhost/SiteName/Default.aspx?TabId=38`

Content:

�w�c�*ϯ�k������Ng��� �.��*�~�W|����ڿ�7������w������7����?���/����w.>��;����&���������������+��_�?

... this goes on for over 10k characters.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that you have a **HTTP compression** problem.

Compression gets tricky when there are multiple compression schemes working simultaneously. In a DotNetNuke installation, you can enable compression with:

- IIS static / dynamic compression
- Telerik RadCompression
- DotNetNuke compression
- 3rd party DNN module like PageBlaster
- Other 3rd party component library, eg. DevExpress
  CallBack compression

ASP.NET postbacks and AJAX callbacks usually fail first. In your case, It looks like you can reach the login page with a GET request, but the postback fails.

Sometimes it is just a specific combination that doesn't work. For example, I've had a situation where IIS 6 + RadCompression + DotNetNuke compression broke postbacks in Firefox 3.6. Chrome and IE were fine, Firefox too with IIS 7.X.

A simple solution to compression problems is to disable 3rd party compression schemes until things work again. IIS compression rarely causes trouble by itself.

#### How to disable Telerik RadCompression

In web.config, remove RadCompression from `httpmodules` and `system.webserver` sections.

[See documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/compression.html).

#### How to disable DotNetNuke compression

If you can get to Host Settings, disable compression in 
Host Settings - Performance Settings - Compression Setting.

[More information](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/04/15/dotnetnuke-performance-settings-explained!.aspx)

[image]

Alternatively, you can update this setting in the database:

```
UPDATE HostSettings
   SET SettingValue = 0
 WHERE SettingName = 'HttpCompression'
```